# PIP 302 errors from inside docker container

Tags: python, docker, pip

I am trying to build a docker image using pip.  The following command works when run from my local desktop:

```
virtualenv venv && \
venv/bin/pip  install -r requirements.txt --index-url <secure URL> --extra-index-url <secure URL>/another directory
```

However, when I run this from inside a docker image, I get 302 errors:

```
Looking in indexes: <secure URL>
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', error('Tunnel connection failed: 302 Found',))': <secure URL>
```

Is there an additional environment setting I need to pass into my Docker container?

Comment: It seems, your container is not able to communicate to outside world. did you used any network config in your Dockerfile/docker-compose.yml file?

Comment: The common reason for this error is when you don't have an internet connection for the container. Can you try restarting you Docker Process?

Comment: My docker container is able to install from repositories using http.  However, it is not able to connect using https.  (i.e http://<url inside the firewall> works, but https://<another url inside the firewall> doesn't work.

Comment: I figured it out.  I was missing certificates inside the docker image.